# Linq to SQL type mismatch

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a type mismatch error when reading the contents of table 'ImageHighlight'.

In designer.cs the table is:

```
public System.Data.Linq.Table<ImageHighlight>ImageHighlights
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetTable<ImageHighlight>();
    }
}
```

In my code I am trying to cache a small table in method `LoadStaticCache()` at `ApplicationStart` so I can access its contents later via `GetHighlightImages()`.

```
public class StaticCache
{

    private static ImageHighlight _images = null;

    public static void LoadStaticCache()
    {
        // Get images - cache using a static member variable
        using (var datacontext = new MHRDataContext())
        {
            _images = datacontext.ImageHighlights;
        }
    }
     public static ImageHighlight GetHighlightImages()
    {
        return _images;
    }
}
```

At code line `_images = datacontext.ImageHighlights;` I get error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Data.Linq.Table<HolidayRentals.Core.Domain.LinqToSql.ImageHighlight>`
>   to `HolidayRentals.Core.Domain.LinqToSql.ImageHighlight`

They are both the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datacontext.ImageHighlights` is a `Table` which is an `IQueryable` of `ImageHighlight`. `_images`s type is `ImageHighlight`. You can not convert these types to each other.

Since you want some caching mechanism and `_images` indicates that it should contain multiple instance of images then you should change the type of `_images`.

Change your code to this:

```
public class StaticCache
{

    private static List<ImageHighlight> _images = null;

    public static void LoadStaticCache()
    {
        // Get images - cache using a static member variable
        using (var datacontext = new MHRDataContext())
        {
            _images = datacontext.ImageHighlights.ToList();
        }
    }
    public static List<ImageHighlight> GetHighlightImages()
    {
        return _images;
    }
}
```